# Result of java.util.Arrays.binarySearch() when input contains duplicates

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates, binary-search

Normally I write binary search function by myself. Now I tried to use build-in function provided by java.util.Arrays. I found something weird that I can't explain. Can someone help?

Consider the following code snippet:

```
1. int[] a = {5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 10};
2. System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(a, 8));
3. System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(a, 0, 7, 8));
4. System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(a, 0, 6, 8));
5. int[] a2 = {5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 10};
6. System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(a2, 8));
```

The output from line 2 and line 3 are 3 which is what I expected (lower bound).
But the output from line 4 and 6 are 4!!!...
I searched Java doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-int:A-int- but didn't find any answer about this.

Comment: How did you miss: *If the array contains multiple elements with the specified value, there is no guarantee which one will be found.* in the Javadoc?

Comment: Yup, you are right. I didn't notice that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Searches a range of the specified array of ints for the specified
>   value using the binary search algorithm. The range must be sorted (as
>   by the sort(int[], int, int) method) prior to making this call. If it
>   is not sorted, the results are undefined. **If the range contains
>   multiple elements with the specified value, there is no guarantee
>   which one will be found.**

Answer (score 0):

The method returns the index of the element you're searching for, and from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(int[],%20int)),

> If the array contains multiple elements with the specified value, there is no guarantee which one will be found.